# beautifulsoup парсит только 100 первых треков плейлиста

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

bs парсит ровно 100 первых треков из плейлиста яндекс музыки

Код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from collections import Counter
s = []

def parse():
    URL = 'https://music.yandex.ru/users/kesols/playlists/1001'
    HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }
    response = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_='d-track__overflowable-column')
    comps = []
    for item in items:
        comps.append({
            'title': item.find('div', class_='d-track__name').get_text(strip=True),
            'artist': item.find('span', class_='d-track__artists').get_text(strip=True)
        })
    global comp
    for comp in comps:
        s.append(comp["artist"])
        print(comp["artist"])
    counter = Counter(s)
    print(counter)

parse()
```

Плейлист:
https://music.yandex.ru/users/kesols/playlists/1001

Comment: Это, конечно, не в тему стека, но в тему вопроса. В магазине приложений Chrome есть расширение YaMuTools. В нем достаточно нажать 1 кнопку Экспортер и у вас будет полный список треков с исполнителями.

Comment: А так в Я.Музыке треки подгружаются по мере прокрутки страницы, попробуйте сначала прокрутить ее вниз до конца и потом парсить.

Comment: Согласен с @Tester. Сам когда то пытался парсить свой плейлист) Нужно прокрутить вниз, то есть догрузить весь список до конца.